# Multiple regressions with loop in loop in R

Tags: r, loops, regression

I want to run the following regressions, the variable which has the problem is EP, is a dummy variable and I must to check different cases, z (lenght=1000) is the threshold variable.  Ι want to crate 1000 different variables of EP from z variable and save the coefficients. I use a loop in loop but the results are completely wrong.The code runs properly and does not make an error. The square brackets and parentheses are the code I run. The problem is that there is a huge delay and the results after two hours still running.

I reduced the sample by 99% and again I did not get a result, the code ran without problem .

I do not want anything special, just for each value of z to run a different regression and end up to stored the estimates. I can not understand why  take so long. Any idea?

```
for (k in 1:1000){ 
  z<-u[k]
  for (i in 1:length(dS)){
    if (dS[i]>=z) {
      EP[i]=1
    } else {
      EP[i]=0
    }

  fitT <- dynlm(dR ~ L(dR,1)+L(EN)+L(EP)+L(ΚΜ,1)
  prob[[k]] <- summary(fitT)$coefficients[1, 2]    
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a closing `}` for the `i`-loop; you also don't have a closing `)` for `dynlm`.

Note, you can really replace your i-loop by

```
EP <- as.integer(dS >= z)
```

Next time when asking question, be clear and specific. What do you mean by "I use a loop in loop but the results are completely wrong"? Error message, etc?

Comment: IMHO the last paragraph belongs to the comment section.